# Text are overflowing to the edge of the screen on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile

On mobile, my website,

http://theglobal-local.com/index.php/passion/

This certain page, where the BucketList section overflows to the edge of the screen?

I've tried adding,

```
overflow:hidden
margin-auto
padding-auto
```

However, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a type, you haven't defined weather you are using px or % in your CSS.

```
padding-left: 40;
padding-right: 40;
```

Should be

```
padding-left: 40px;
padding-rigjt: 40px;
```